# Pushdown Automation with unequal elements

Tags: pushdown-automaton

There is a language L = {0,1}^* and the thing is that 1 and 0 are not supposed to be of the equal number. How can I present that in a PDA automaton?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A PDA can read input, push onto a stack, and pop off of a stack. When trying to design automata, especially PDAs and TMs, I like to think of input strings as long rows of colored marbles or chips lined up on a table. The question then is how, using only a single stack and picking up chips from left to right, can you tell whether a row of chips has a different number of red and blue chips?

One method is the following. When you pick up a marble, look at the stack. If the stack is empty or has the same color chip on top, put your chip down. If the topmost chip has a different color, throw the chip you picked up and the topmost chip from the stack into a bag. Continue until you've picked up all the chips. Now look at the stack. If the stack is empty, that means you must have thrown away the same number of red and blue chips. If you have some chips in the stack, that means there were chips you couldn't throw away. Indeed, the color of the chips remaining tells you what kind of chip was more numerous.